# Complex rounding with non-standard intervals in Excel

Tags: excel, rounding, intervals

I need to round a calculated number to the closest value in a table.  The values in the table are not sequential, and the intervals between the values are not the same.  (I actually haven't been able to find a pattern between the values.)

Here are the table values:

```
1
10
20
40
70
120
180
260
360
610
940
1350
1780
2220
2720
3490
4770
6500
8070
10000
```

So for instance, if I have a calculated number of `53.36`, the formula should return a table value of `40`.  If the value was above `55`, then it would return `70`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. It should be posted on superuser.com, not here.

Answer (score 2):

Use vlookup with a final parameter of 1 or true (not exact match).

Put your values in a range and vlookup on that range. It will find the nearest value that is not greater than the search value.

Edit:
And...by the way, your numbers listed are WARF (weighted average rating factor) numbers used by Moody's in rating bonds. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=7Us_LVHirhAC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=1%2010%2020%2040%2070%20120%20180%20260%20360%20610%20940%201350%201780%202220%202720%203490%204770%206500%208070%2010000&source=bl&ots=-VDrtq0FU3&sig=203kq_DzJq7WfcXlse3QqlXpQbI&hl=en&ei=Y0ZJTtOINI2HsALnpdWRCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=1%2010%2020%2040%2070%20120%20180%20260%20360%20610%20940%201350%201780%202220%202720%203490%204770%206500%208070%2010000&f=false).

Edit #2: To get the "rounding up" you're looking for, just have a second column in your search range that has the next number up. E.g.: On the row where 20 is, the second column would show 40; on the row for 40, the second column would show 70. Then, in your formula, hava second vlookup on the same search range, but returning the second column. Once you've got the two numbers (40 and 70 for your example value of 55), you can do the math in your formula to determine which you'll show.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the quick response! And for figuring out the relationship between the numbers. Your suggestion somewhat works, but only if the values fall below halfway between the intervals. For instance, a calculated number of 67 that uses vlookup with a parameter of 1 returns a value of 40 instead of 70. It isn't/doesn't round to the actual closest value.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a quick and easy if then loop using VBA. Check the difference between your number and the next 2 numbers in the list. When the difference is less with the first number you know that's the one you want to return.

Comment: Excel doesn't have if-then loops. You'd have to go to VBA for that, which is overkill for this application.

Comment: Overkill? Really? A simple code with a few lines is worse than having to create another column of data in order to round up? You have to be kidding me.

Comment: And please remember down votes are for when an answer is not helpful - just because you dont think VBA isn't the best approach does not mean the answer is any less appropriate than your own.

Comment: I agree that a VBA program is not a good choice for this task -- but what is this question doing on a programming site in the first place? If the OP doesn't want programming-related answer, then OP should not post on a programming Q&A site. Go to superuser.com instead

Comment: @Issun: Your original post didn't mention VBA, just if-then loops. That was the reason for the downvote, since there are no if-then loops in Excel. I'm the one who mentioned VBA, and I'm glad you modified your answer to reflect that. The VBA route is still going to involve more effort than a formula and extra column, but I've removed the downvote, because the downvote had nothing to do with effort, but rather applicability.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about an Array function (aka CSE Function). If your table is in range A1:A20, and your lookup value is in C1, then use this function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1+MIN(ABS(A$1:A$20-C1)),A$1:A$20,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(C1-MIN(ABS(A$1:A$20-C1)),A$1:A$20,1,FALSE))
```

and then Control-Shift-Enter (not just Enter). 
Basically, this finds the minimum absolute difference between C1 and any value in your table. Then it tries adding it and doing a VLOOKUP to see if it's in the table, if that fails, it subtracts it and does VLOOKUP. A little complicated, but might give you ideas.